# Find the difference between 1 column depending on date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I run this:

```
SELECT NAME FROM T1
WHERE _LOAD_DATETIME::date = '2022-01-31'
```

I see 62 rows

but when I do

```
SELECT NAME FROM T1
WHERE _LOAD_DATETIME::date = '2022-02-01'
```

I see 59

I want to see what NAME's are missing when it ran for _LOAD_DATETIME::date = '2022-02-01'

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
SELECT NAME FROM table
WHERE _LOAD_DATETIME::date = '2022-02-01' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT NAME FROM 
table
WHERE _LOAD_DATETIME::date = '2022-01-31')
```

Comment: I'm using Snowflake, I've added the tag just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `MINUS` for your purposes:

```
SELECT NAME FROM T1
WHERE _LOAD_DATETIME::date = '2022-01-31'
MINUS
SELECT NAME FROM T1
WHERE _LOAD_DATETIME::date = '2022-02-01'
```

If we are talking about `PostgreSQL`, you have to use `EXCEPT` instead of `MINUS`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two [set operators MINUS or EXCEPT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#minus-except) you can use (they are aliases for each other)

SELECT column1 FROM values (1),(2),(3),(4)
MINUS
SELECT column1 FROM values (2),(3),(4),(5);

gives `1` if you want to see `5` you need to flip the order of SELECTs.